# How to do this with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, mouseclick-event

So disclaimer i am horrendous at knockout. What I want to be able to do is what im doing here with jquery and instead use knockout.I was told that using a click event would be a good way to go. Any tips/ help would be great!

html

```
<div id="1" class="profile">
1
</div>
<div id="2"  class="profile">
2
</div>
<div id="3"  class="profile">
3
</div>
<div id="4"  class="profile">
4
</div>
<div id="5"  class="profile">
5
</div>
<div id="6"  class="profile">
6
</div>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="save-button"/>
<div style="clear:both;">Number Of Points</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

CSS

```
.profile{
width: 50px;
height: 80px;
color: #FFF;
background: black;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
float: left;

}
.highlight {
background: yellow !important;
border:1px solid #000;
color: black;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});

$('#save-button').click(function(){
$('#output').html('');
$('div.highlight').each(function(){
    $('#output').append('<div>' + $(this).attr('id') + '</div>')
});
});
```

Here is what I have so far( using jquery not knockout)
http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/VFNss/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (sorry it used underscore for the computed, but this made it a little simpler):

HTML:

```
<div style="clear:both; height: 150px;">
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="profile" data-bind="text: name, click: clickme, enable: active, css:{highlight: active()}"></div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>Selected Items</h2>
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: save" value="Save">
```

## JS

```
function Step(number) {
    this.active = ko.observable(false);
    this.name = ko.observable("Point " + number);

    this.clickme = function () {
        this.active(!this.active());
    };
}

var model = function () {
    var items = ko.observableArray([new Step(1), new Step(2), new Step(3), new Step(4)]);
    var selectedItems = ko.computed(function () {
        return _.filter(items(), function (item) {
            return item.active();
        });
    })

    var save = function () {
        alert("sending items \n" + ko.toJSON(selectedItems()));
    }

    return {
        items: items,
        selectedItems: selectedItems,
        save: save
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

## CSS

```
.profile {
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    float: left;
}
.highlight {
    background: yellow !important;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color: black;
}
```

## ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/zYsv7/1/))

Comment: This is awesome! Thank You so much! I have one question, if it is possible how would I go about making it only be able to select one at a time?

Comment: Do you mean prevent someone from selecting a new one when one is selected or deselecting the old one when a new one is selected? :)

Comment: It's a little crude, but you can do it like this, notice how i have moved the click event for the item and allowed the view model to handle this. http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/zYsv7/4/

Comment: deslecting the old one

Comment: So to be a further pain in the ass , would it be possible to explain how this works?  can eventually make stuff on my own instead of begging the internet for help haha. Thanks

Comment: Knockout for me was a mindset change, using MVVM you are concentrating more about the data than how it is presented. The code is simply manipulating the data and knockout is displaying it for me based on the bindings (the data-bind things in html). Try out the excellent tutorial section of their site http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ when you are done there, have a look at their documentation, search for each of the bindings i use and you can see what they are doing then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another (simplistic) alternative using the built in Knockout array functions instead of Underscore.js ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFNss/7/)):

### HTML

```
<!-- ko foreach: numbers -->
<div class="profile" data-bind="text: val, click: $root.clicked"></div>
<!-- /ko -->

<button type="button" data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
<div style="clear:both;">Number Of Points</div>
<div id="output" data-bind="foreach: highlightedNumbers">
    <div data-bind="text: val"></div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var numberdata = [{ val: '1', highlight: false },{ val: '2', highlight: false },{ val: '3', highlight: false },
                 { val: '4', highlight: false },{ val: '5', highlight: false },{ val: '6', highlight: false }];

function Number(data){
    this.val = ko.observable(data.val);
    this.highlight = ko.observable(data.highlight);
};

function viewmodel(){
    var self = this;
    this.numbers = ko.observableArray();

    this.highlightedNumbers = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = [];      
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.numbers(), function(num){          
            if(num.highlight())items.push(num);
        });

        return items;
    }, this);

    this.loadData = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, num){
            self.numbers.push(new Number(num));
        });
    };

    this.clicked = function(num, e){       
        var status = !num.highlight(),
            $div = $(e.target);

        num.highlight(status);

        if(status)$div.addClass('highlight');
        else $div.removeClass('highlight');
    }

    this.save = function(){
        // not implemented
    };

};

var vm = new viewmodel();
vm.loadData(numberdata);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: I forgot about the ko utility, nice :)